# How to search page content in firefox history (like is possible in Google Chrome)?

Tags: firefox, search, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to search the text of my browsing history in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/296501/is-there-a-way-to-search-the-text-of-my-browsing-history-in-firefox)

In Google Chrome it is possible to search the *content* of the pages in your search history (I suppose Chrome makes use of Google (the search engine/database) in the background to be able to do so).

Is there some way to make this possible in Firefox as well?

Currently, as far as I know, in Firefox you can only search for terms appearing the url or title of pages.
However,

Comment: I answered this in another topic before I saw this one. http://superuser.com/q/296501/85930