# Is there a way to search the text of my browsing history in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search, firefox-extensions, browser-cache

I often find myself in the situation where I know I saw something in a web page recently, but don't remember where.  I would therefore like to be able to do a full-text search of the contents of my web history in Firefox.  Is there an extension that will do this?

I am aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/42492/full-text-search-of-browser-history-through-the-browser).  However, I am only interested in Firefox solutions, and the only Firefox option in that question seems to no longer be relevant (add-on has changed).

My requirements for a solution to this problem:

- Must work in Firefox.
- Must work locally - I do not want to send my history or bookmarks to a 3rd-party service to get this functionality (so [InfoAxe](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/infoaxe-web-history-search-and/) is out as near as I can tell).
- Must be a high-quality, reputable extension (fuzzy, I know, but many extensions smell sketchy).
- Must work in Linux (so Google Desktop is out so far as I know).
- Strongly prefer open source solution.

Does anyone know of such an extension?

Comment: Pretty much the same question, just saw: http://superuser.com/questions/277023/how-to-search-page-content-in-firefox-history-like-is-possible-in-google-chrome

Comment: any new stuff about this topic? fetching.io looks like its not maintained any more, and so is recallmonkey.

Answer (score 5):

Mozilla Labs has something called RecallNonkey that's being developed for this purpose. http://mozillalabs.com/prospector/2011/06/20/recallmonkey-finds-what-you-forget/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-recall-monkey/

This is a local search against the history entries in the places database and I don't believe it sends any information out there - it's still pretty new/experimental but I've been using it for a little while and it seems to work well.

Comment: I should add, https://github.com/mozilla/prospector/tree/master/recallMonkey - not clear what the license is from the source but I've asked for clarification.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/prospector/issues/583#issuecomment-1540712 confirms that it's under an open source license (MPL).

Comment: RecallMonkey does not seem to include a fulltext index of the browsing history. It rather provides a refinable search of the existing history data using a webpage UI. So no more than URLs and page titles can be searched. Unfortunately.

Comment: another way (only if when you use Firefox you are logged to Google account) is search for inside history via Google cache

Answer (score 2):

Use `recoll` desktop search along with the `recollweb` firefox extension. This copies visited pages to local cache that recoll indexes.

Recoll desktop search: http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/

Firefox extension: http://recollfirefox.sourceforge.net/